# Header file not found in framework Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

In my xcode project there are 5 work space .My app depends on other four.I already added all the dependencies in the project and required frameworks, but still it is showing not found error.I set the framework search path also.I have added all the related static libraries also.

Comment: could you post some error or code where your problem occures

Comment: When I am building , in one of the class it fails and the error is <Framwork/HeaderFile.h> not found.

Comment: Add header file to framework public check if available in your project

Comment: Did you drag the framework project into your workspace, or just add the lib?

Comment: if not..drag in your framework project from the finder and then try linking it.